# I want to create a nft as a hotel room ticket. Is it possible?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft

I am a PHP user but a complete novice in blockchain.

I want to create a nft as a hotel room ticket.
I would like to sell them on platforms such as opensensea.
Is it realistically possible to implement the following?

1: Can only be used once.
2: It has an expiration date.
3: After use, the design of the nft will change for used.
4: If holder don't use it and the expiration date has passed, the design will change to used.

From my research, it seems that the "expiration date" can be implemented.

What I find problematic is

3: "After use, the nft design will change to used".

I'm not sure how to do this automatically, so I'd prefer to do it manually.
For example, is it possible to manually rewrite the data of nft "A" to "used" when the holder of nft "A" makes a hotel reservation?

I would appreciate any advice you can give me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it's possible.

OpenSea extracts the NFT's metadata from the url returns by the tokenURI function of the NFT smart contract. So you can achieve the goal by overriding this function.

```
function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(_tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

    string memory baseURI = _baseURI();

    //Implement the features you want to add
    //Imagine there is already structure called TicketInfo that stores information of NFTs and "used" NFT has zero index in the collection
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenId;
    TicketInfo storage ticket = ticketInfo[tokenId];
    if(ticket.expirationDate < now || ticket.isUsed) tokenId = 0;

    return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString())) : "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to do it like you taught me!

Comment: You are welcome. Plz let me know if you have any issue.